# Event that is taking place after inline edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have jqgrid, which sends row's data to another view (MVC4) when row is selected. But when I edit row's info (I'm using inline edit) this view  doesn't changed. And I can't find event that is taking place after inline edit. This is js, what should I change to change my view after row editing

```
  $(function () {
$("#GridTable").jqGrid({
    url: "/Goods/GoodsList",
    editurl: "/Goods/Edit",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    colNames: ['GoodId', 'Имя', 'Цена'],
    colModel: [
        { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'GoodId', index: 'GoodId', editable: true },
        {
            key: false, name: 'GoodName', index: 'GoodName', editable: true, sortable: true,
            editrules: {
                required: true, custom: true, custom_func: notATag
            }
        },
        {
            key: false, name: 'Price', index: 'Price', editable: true, sortable: true, formatter: numFormat,
            unformat: numUnformat,
            //sorttype: 'float',
            editrules: { required: true, custom: true, custom_func: figureValid}
        }, ],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Список товаров',
    sortable: true,
    emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
    cellsubmit : 'remote',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0"
    },
    //to get good's full view when row is selected
    onSelectRow:

        function () {
            var myGrid = $('#GridTable'),
            selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
            celValue = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'GoodId');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Goods/DetailInfo",
                type: "GET",
                data: { id: celValue }
            })
            .done(function (partialViewResult) {
                $("#goodDetInfo").html(partialViewResult);
            });
        },
    //to change good's full view after row deleting
    loadComplete: function(data){
        var myGrid = $('#GridTable'),
            selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
            celValue = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'GoodId');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Goods/DetailInfo",
            type: "GET",
            data: { id: celValue }
        })
        .done(function (partialViewResult) {
            $("#goodDetInfo").html(partialViewResult);
        });
    },
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false
}).navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: true },
    {
        // edit options
        zIndex: 100,
        url: '/Goods/Edit',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
            var myGrid = $('#GridTable'),
            selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
            celValue = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'GoodId');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Goods/DetailInfo",
                type: "GET",
                data: { id: celValue }
            })
            .done(function (partialViewResult) {
                $("#goodDetInfo").html(partialViewResult);
            });
        }
    },
    {
        // add options
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/Goods/Create",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,

        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        // delete options
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/Goods/Delete",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterDelete: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    });

$('#GridTable').inlineNav('#pager', {
    edit: true,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    cancel: true,
    editParams: {
        keys: true,
        afterSubmit: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
            var myGrid = $('#GridTable'),
            selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
            celValue = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'GoodId');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Goods/DetailInfo",
                type: "GET",
                data: { id: celValue }
            })
            .done(function (partialViewResult) {
                $("#goodDetInfo").html(partialViewResult);
            });
        }
    },
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The properties and callback function of `editParams` parameter of `inlineNav` can be found [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow). What you need is probably `aftersavefunc` or `successfunc` instead of `afterSubmit`, which exist only in form editing method (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events)). The parameters of `aftersavefunc` or `successfunc` callbacks are described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) (as parameters of `saveRow`), but the parameters depend on the version of jqGrid, which you use and from the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I develop free jqGrid fork and I would recommend you to use the current (4.13.3) version of free jqGrid.